# How to resolve conflicted dependency versions when import frame_support

Tags: rust, cargo

I'm trying to pull on-chain asset data from Basilisk via subxt. The name field of this `asset_details` struct is a BoundedVec and I need to be able to run the `into_inner()` method to get the vec from inside the BoundedVec.

[image]

To get access to the method I need to add the frame_support crate as a dependency to my crate. I've tried many tweaks to this dependency but I always get some crazy dependency tree error that I don't know how to solve. Is it really this hard to get access to frame_support? Any ideas appreciated!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

(Preferably dump text rather than images as we can copy paste and try things).

In this case I would suggest pulling in the sp-keyring from master substrate:
https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/primitives/keyring

That should mean that it is compatible with the frame support version you are pulling in.